# How to execute a win32 console based executable programmatically and read the console output

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a win32 console based .exe.

I want to execute this .exe from a win32 GUI application programmatically and read the console output.

e.g. c:\Test.exe is the location of the console based program and I want to execute this program from another GUI application.

output at the console could be a "string" with information.

I understand I can use CreateProcess to execute an application but how do I capture the output of the application.

Thanks

Comment: This may be of use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Create a pipe. Attach the write end of the pipe to the standard output of the new process. Read from the read end of the pipe. Take care to make the handle to the write end of the pipe inheritable.

Answer (score 0):

try redirecting the output to a text file  `test.exe >out.txt` You can even but this line in a .bat file if you need it for some automatic testing.